# When I turn monitor off, it won't turn back on?

Tags: display

Monitor functions perfectly until I turn it off. Then when I press the power button again, the monitor won't react. My monitor is an ASUS PA246 ips display if that helps at all.

To get it back on, I had to turn the power switch off and switch to a different outlet. Is this an issue with my outlet or the monitor? No monitor has previously done this. I'm trying to see if there's a hassle-free way to actually turn my monitor on/off.

Comment: Do you have a another monitor around to test it with at all?

Comment: I've tested 2 other monitors, and they work fine. I'll try plugging the ASUS into a different computer.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to check this would be to try this monitor on another computer, and/or try another monitor on this computer.

Also, next time this happens, try turning the monitor off and unplugging the cable that connects the monitor to the computer video. Then wait about 30 seconds, and re-attach the video cable, and re-power the monitor.

If that works, it could have something to do with the standby/sleep functions between the monitor and the motherboard.

The monitor may think there is no computer attached and may go into standby (powersave) mode blanking the screen.

Or the computer may think there is no monitor attached so it is turning off the video signals to the monitor.

Comment: Where can I adjust these settings?

Comment: I'm not sure which settings you are referring to. The monitor looks for active video signals from the computer before it will "wake-up", and the computer (video card) looks for connectivity through the cable to the monitor before it will supply video signals. Has this monitor been working fine with this computer then recently developed these symptoms ?

Comment: I don't think there is any adjustment possible with these functions. The only relevant issue I can think of is the level (voltage) of the video signals to the monitor. Perhaps a "weak" connection in the video cable.

Comment: Another thing to try would be to enter the BIOS setup, and try turning the monitor off and back on while there. If that works reliably, then it's almost certainly a software or driver issue somewhere, not a hardware problem.

Answer (score 1):

My old Philips 190BW monitor behaves in the same manner. 
To force it to wake up I simply change resolution in my Windows system pressing CTRL + ALT + DEL. The monitor senses che resolution change and wakes up.

Comment: Nice. What's the CANC button?

Comment: Sorry, it was referred to a not English keyboard. It was the DEL button. Answer fixed.